# Rails filtering records in many to many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have many to many relationship for books and authors like:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books_authors, inverse_of: :author, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :authors, through: :books_authors
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books_authors, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, through: :books_authors
end

class AuthorsBook < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Now to get all the `Books` with `Authors` of `ids: 1 and 3`
The query is like :

```
Book.joins(:authors).where(authors: {id:  [1, 3]}).uniq

Book.joins(:books_authors).where(books_authors: {author_id:  [1,3]}).uniq

Book.joins(:authors).where('authors.id IN (?)', [1,3]).uniq
```

But I get a book whose authors' ids are `2,3,5`, which should not be the case, as it does not have `author` with id `1`.

So , how could I only get the books with given authors ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `having` clause in there combined with your where clause:

```
ids = [1,3]
Book
  .select('books.*') # not sure if this is necessary
  .where(authors_books: { author_id: ids })
  .joins(:authors_books)
  .group('books.id')
  .having('count(authors_books) >= ?', ids.size)
```

The SQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i7TXPJgavLwQCHb4GhgH3b/0

Comment: So i was missing the having check along with group by