# How to create a Rails scope that matches multiple HABTM records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails 5 app acting like a CMS, with `Story` and `Tag` models. A story `has_and_belongs_to_many :tags`. I want to create a scope in which I can pass multiple tags and get all stories that have ALL the tags I pass to it.

For example:

```
story_1.tags   # => [tag_a, tag_c]
story_2.tags   # => [tag_b, tag_c]
story_3.tags   # => [tag_a, tag_b, tag_c]

# Desired behavior
Story.with_tags([tag_a, tag_c])  # => [story_1, story_3]
Story.with_tags([tag_b, tag_c])  # => [story_2, story_3]
Story.with_tags([tag_a, tag_b])  # => [story_3]
```

I've tried making a single `with_tag` scope and chaining multiple together, but it seems to make a query that attempts to find a single join record where the tag ID is 1 AND 3, which returns nothing.

```
  def self.with_tag(tag)
    joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: tag })
  end

Story.with_tag(tag_a).with_tag(tag_c)  # => []
```

I've also tried passing all the tag IDs into a single where clause on the join table, but then I get all stories that have any of the tags (more of an OR query, I'm looking for an AND)

```
  def self.with_tags(tags)
    joins(:stories_tags).where(stories_tags: { tag_id: tags }).distinct
  end

Story.with_tags([tag_a, tag_c])  # => [story_1, story_2, story_3]
```

Comment: Joining and querying on the `tags` table has the same behavior as using the `stories_tags` join table in either scenario above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a SQL `HAVING` clause:

```
ids = [1,2,3]
Story.joins(:tags)
  .where(:tags => { id: ids })
  .group('stories.id')
  .having('count(tags.id) >= ?', ids.size)
#                         ^^ if you want to get stories having exactly the tags 
#                            provided, use equal instead
```

---

Similar question: [Rails filtering records in many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260550/rails-filtering-records-in-many-to-many-relationship/54260825?noredirect=1#comment95349709_54260825)